# Could number-theoretic "statistical independence" results (e.g. Chowla's conjecture) be used to disprove superdeterminism?

Tags: quantum-interpretations, correlation-functions, bells-inequality, determinism

I will admit I only have the most basic understanding of superdeterminism, from this PBSspacetime video, in particular at this link https://youtu.be/JnKzt6Xq-w4?t=584 (I have provided the relevant timestamp). My understanding is this: superdeterminism is the idea that the violation of Bell's inequality is actually due to being unable to take statistically independent measurements.

My idea is this: what if we use some number theoretic quantities to decide how to measure our entangled particles, for example Alice and Bob (in the language of the video linked above), could take measurements based on the values of the Liouville function $\lambda(n)$ and $\lambda(n+1)$, respectively. Then, something like the Chowla conjecture (the logarithmically-averaged version is already proven, see https://joelmoreira.wordpress.com/2018/11/04/taos-proof-of-logarithmically-averaged-chowlas-conjecture-for-two-point-correlations/), would give some sort of quantification of how "independent" the "random variables" $\lambda(n)$ and $\lambda(n+1)$ are: quoting [Terry Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/10/14/the-chowla-conjecture-and-the-sarnak-conjecture/) (with minor edits to fit the scenario I've set up):

> The Chowla conjecture resembles an assertion that, for $n$ chosen randomly and uniformly from $1$ to $x$, the random variables $\lambda(n),\lambda(n+1)$ become asymptotically independent of each other (in the probabilistic sense) as $x\to\infty$.

Would it be possible to give some quantification as to how correlated Alice's and Bob's choices of measurements must be in order for Bell's inequality to be violated based on failure of statistical independence alone, and then perform a Bell test using the Liouville function as described above, and derive some sort of contradiction between the quantified correlation of Alice's and Bob's choices vs. the quantified uncorrelation of $\lambda(n),\lambda(n+1)$ from the Chowla conjecture?

---

Basically my idea comes from hearing that

> Some have argued that superdeterminism requires a kind of conspiracy of interactions to ensure
> that two messy meat computers make the right choices based on marginal interactions arbitrarily
> far in the past.

([timestamp from PBSspacetime video](https://youtu.be/JnKzt6Xq-w4?t=672)), while many results in analytic number are about *disproving* conspiracies in the primes/prime factorizations (this language I think was popularized by Terry Tao, see [MSE question about it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116981/what-is-the-intuitive-meaning-of-conspiracy-in-number-theory))/proving statistical randomness in primes/prime factorizations, e.g. Chowla's conjecture for Liouville or Mobius functions which I mentioned, and even the Riemann hypothesis itself (see [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2350052/riemann-hypothesis-random-walks-and-m%C3%B6bius-function)) is equivalent to the Mobius/[Liouville](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446822/what-is-the-origin-of-this-riemann-hypothesis-equivalent-involving-the-liouville) functions essentially behaving like random walks.